# Hard Drive doesn't show up in "Computer", but does in BIOS and Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive

I just installed Ubuntu, because Windows XP is no longer supported. I only use this old PC for internet and music.

Installation went OK. But now that I want to load everything I backed up, my 320gb HD isn't showing up in "Computer", but it does show up in BIOS, and Terminal, and Disk Utility!?

Can I do anything to make it show up in "Computer"? If so, how?

If not, then is there another way to load all my files?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have installed Ubuntu on 320GB HD which you have already used for WinXP.

The problem may occur if you have selected "Erase and Use the entire disk" option while installing Ubuntu which might have formatted your partition.

If not, please check whether you see any disk drives under "Devices" option to the left, while viewing the "Home" folder. By double clicking on the devices, it will mount automatically and you can see the files that are in Windows Xp.

Please provide some more details to give you the correct answer.

Comment: After Clicking the "Home Folder", the only thing that shows up in "Devices" is "Floppy Drive".

Comment: The HD does show up in Disk Utility, BIOS, and Terminal. I even ran that "Smart Data Test" on that, and it passed.Ubuntu is the only Operation System currently on this PC now, as I erased Windows XP from it.

Comment: I've tried Disconnecting it, and reconnecting it, then restarting the PC to see if that would help any, but Nope. It still won't show up. I also connected an external HD to this PC to see if it wo9uld show up, and it did. Under "Devices" it shows it, but not the 320gb Internal HD.

Comment: If Ubuntu is installed on the 320GB hard disk, then it will NOT shown under "Devices". Since you have erased XP, all the data might have been formatted. Just post me the output of `df -lh`

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       292G  3.6G  273G   2% /
udev            991M  4.0K  991M   1% /dev
tmpfs           200M  836K  200M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1000M   80K 1000M   1% /run/shm

Comment: I'm new to to Ubuntu, so does everything look normal on that Terminal result? Also, I tried loading and downloading programs such as iTunes and Google Earth, among other things, and it wont let me. I'll try to do those things again so I can copy and past the results.